# jQuery to remove &nbsp;s but without using .html() which re-creates everything

Tags: jquery

I have lots of elements within CKEditor with events hooked up to them and data bound to them using the .data() method. I would like to remove any &nbsp;s from this block of HTML. I could simply do

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/&nbsp\;/, ''));
```

But because this resets the HTML it effectivly re-creates all of the elements which means that I have to re-bind all of the events and data. What I am currently doing is this:

```
if ($body.html().indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1) {
    $body.find(':*:not(:has(*))').each(function(){
            // These nodes don't have any children so contain text or nothing
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp\;/,''));
    });
}
```

This will replace &nbsp;s in HTML like this:

```
     <p>Foo&nbsp;Bar</p>
```

But not in HTML like this:

```
     <div>Foo&nbsp;<span>Bar</span></div>
```

Can anyone think of a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select all text nodes inside of the target element then loop through them making your replacement.

```
$("*").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function(){
    // do your replace here using this.nodeValue
});
```

I highly suggest filtering down to a smaller subset of elements if possible, `'*'` and `'body *'` will probably be slow.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the contents function and had forgotten about the nodeType attribute. This will only be for small snippets of HTML so performance shouldn't be a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your first code `$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/&nbsp\;/, ''));` is correct. you just have to add `g` in the end in order to replace all the occurences and make sure you call this function on document load like here..

`$('document').ready(function () {
    $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/&nbsp\;/g, ''));
});`

Comment: The only downside to this is it will result in all events and data being lost on all descendants of the body tag, which is the one thing the OP is trying to avoid.